# multiple selection on keyboard for datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts, multipleselection

I need to create a few keyboard shortcuts for a `datagridview`. 
I need to allow the user to select *multiple* rows without using the mouse. *e.g.* in windows explorer you can:
Hold `Ctrl` *(select first)*
`Up/down` *(move to next selection)*
`Space` *(select others)*.
Is this possible to do in `C#`?

Comment: `Shift`+`Arrow Keys` should work fine.  Or do you mean to highlight non-consecutive rows?

Comment: @OhBeWise yes I mean non-consecutive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> already have default behaviors (such as navigating to the left-most, right-most, top-most, and bottom-most cells respectively), you'll have to inherit from the `DataGridView` class and override the `ProcessDataGridViewKey` method to handle these user actions as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for selecting a row.

```
public class MultSelectKeyDGV : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs = null;
        DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selectedCells = null;
        bool selectRow = false;

        if (e.Control)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Down:
                    keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Down);
                    selectedCells = this.SelectedCells;
                    break;
                case Keys.Up:
                    keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Up);
                    selectedCells = this.SelectedCells;
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Right);
                    selectedCells = this.SelectedCells;
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Left);
                    selectedCells = this.SelectedCells;
                    break;
                case Keys.Space:
                    keyEventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.None);
                    selectRow = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    keyEventArgs = e;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            keyEventArgs = e;
        }

        bool result = base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(keyEventArgs);

        if (e.Control)
        {
            this.CurrentRow.Selected = selectRow;
            this.KeepSelected(selectedCells); 
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void KeepSelected(DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selected)
    {
        if (selected != null && this.MultiSelect)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in selected)
            {
                cell.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now just replace your instance of the `DataGridView` object in your `Form` with an instance of this class and you're done.

[image: Screen-shot of Keyboard selecting rows]